# How can I open an nxs file with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I have a Nexus file (foo.nxs) with direct data from measurements and I wish to open it with pandas. However, when I try the typical

```
HDFStore('foo.nxs') or read_hdf('foo.nxs','/group')
```

It just returns an empty Store:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: /foo.nxs
Empty
```

or the TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

All examples in the docs page start by creating a hdf file, storing data in it and then retrieving it, but this is done from the same pandas. I want to know whether it's possible to read an hdf file which was not previously generated with pandas.

Here's a part of the output from ptdump, as requested by @Jeff:

```
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
    [HDF5_Version := '1.8.11',
    NeXus_version := '4.3.0',
    file_name := '/Messdaten/C9/20140423/messung_21h14m01.197.nxs',
    file_time := '2014-04-23T21:14:01+01:00']
/exp_root.Kerr.DoublePulse2D.SuperDuperScan_V2_00001 (Group) ''
  /exp_root.Kerr.DoublePulse2D.SuperDuperScan_V2_00001._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 1 attributes:
   [NX_class := 'NXentry']
/exp_root.Kerr.DoublePulse2D.SuperDuperScan_V2_00001/scan_data (Group) ''
  /exp_root.Kerr.DoublePulse2D.SuperDuperScan_V2_00001/scan_data._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 1 attributes:
   [NX_class := 'NXdata']
/exp_root.Kerr.DoublePulse2D.SuperDuperScan_V2_00001/scan_data/actuator_1_1 (CArray(5, 121), zlib(6)) ''
  atom := Float64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0.0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (5, 121)
```

Comment: But is this `.nxs` file an hdf file? I mean, nexus uses hdf as the underlying binary format, but is it also a normal hdf file?

Comment: ``HDFStore`` can read a plain-vanilla ``PyTables`` table format that is not created with meta-data (that pandas normally uses), http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#external-compatibility. post ``ptdump -av foo.nxs``.

Comment: @Jeff ptdump outputs for my file the names of the groups and nodes with their data contents and their corresponding attributes, as in any hdf5. So it cannot be done?

Comment: it would help to *show* what ptdump outputs

Comment: hard to read that, better to edit your question.

Comment: @Jeff here you have! I'd appreciate your thoughts, since I'm stuck here, can't figure out how to deal with nxs and pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a plain vanilla PyTables store. So these are actually pretty easy to read (and don't need pandas), but this will show you how you can read them (as numpy arrays).

```
with pd.get_store('test.h5') as store:
     data = store.root.exp_root.Kerr.DoublePulse2D.SuperDuperScan_V2_00001/scan_data/actuator_1_1.read()
```

docs are [here](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html#reading-data-from-array-objects).

This just grabs the PyTables root node and reads the data in. This is in `CArray` format, and is a simple array.

`HDFStore` will be able to read plain-vanilla PyTables `Table` objects (with out the meta data), but simple enough to just read in arrays.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wanting to retrieve the whole file into one object that already contains the labels. Otherwise I can do this easily with `tables.openFile().getNode().read()`. I thought that pandas advantage was being able to handle labeled data, but if you cannot read it directly from a file, then what is it good for?

Comment: ``HDFStore`` is built on top of PyTables, so you can certainly read in the data using the lower level functions. You can also read in the data and write to a new store in the proper format if you wish. Your stored format may have meta-data but pandas is not setup to guess at arbitrary formats. If this is a popular format, you may wish to write and contribute a converter.